# Java: documenting a static initializer yields a InvalidJavadocPosition in checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle, static-initializer

I endowed a static initializer with a javadoc comment.
Now I face that checkstyle complains considering it an InvalidJavadocPosition.

Is this a bug or correct? If the latter how to document a static initializer??

Comment: *"Is this a bug or correct?"* - It is correct. *"If the latter how to document a static initializer??"* - Put the documentation in the class javadoc.  Or in regular comments.  If you are using static initializers in some way that *requires* javadoc documentation (i.e. it affects things outside of the class) then you are probably using static initializers inappropriately.